# Select highest/lowest value for x in Data Object

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

my

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Creditcard")
@AdditionalCriteria( ..... )

public class Customer implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name ="CustomerId")
    private long customerId;
    @Column(name = "cardNumber");
    private String cardNumber;
    @Column(name = "apply_date")
    private java.sql.Date date;
}
```

Example Table Data for CustomerID 1234:

```
CustomerId|cardNumber|apply_date|....other fields
----------|----------|----------|----------------
0000000123|0000000001|2013-01-01|----------------
0000000123|0000000002|2013-09-10|----------------
```

Yes, I know, the Primary Key has to be a Composite Key (EmbeddedID), but I still have to figure it out.

Due to the @AdditionalCriteria I only get 1 entry (because the other card is "banned")
but I need to get the 'apply_date' from cardNumber '1'.

Is something like that possible?

Like:

```
@Column(name = "apply_date")
@GetMinValue(field_name = "CustomerId")
private java.sql.Date date;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your entity should represent a row in the database, not all rows.  So your entity probably should be a "CreditCard" entity, using "cardNumber" as the primary key, or what ever uniquely identifies the database row.

Then, since CustomerId seems to be a foreign key probably to a table that has customer data, you would have a Customer Entity that has a 1:M relationship to CreditCards.  This customer entity could then have a transient date attribute that you set in a JPA postLoad event, getting the value from a JPQL query : "select cc.date from CreditCard cc where cc.customerId = :customerId";

Setting up an Customer entity that only uses a single card/row from a CreditCard table seems like a bad idea, as what will you do when the customer gets another creditCard assigned - it is the same customer, but a new card.  If you use separate entity objects, you just keep the same Customer entity and assign a new creditcard object.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I've solved it using @PostLoad and a NativeQuery. I can't change anything in the Database unfortunatly.